# Flagging Help: Is it neccesary to flag comments that are 'chatty' but stick to the question?

Tags: support, flags

I was on stackoverflow just a second ago, and I saw a post with a lot of comments but they weren't spam nor offproper, and they pertained to the question.
Should I flag it? Is it proper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are actually widely considered to be the equivalent of temporary post-it notes left on a question or answer.  They're not searchable, they can't be voted up or down and ranked in the same manner as answers. Thus, they're really intended just to help improve a post or to seek clarification.

If you see a long comment thread, here's what you can do to help:

- Edit helpful, relevant information into the body of the post, then flag the comments as obsolete.
- If there isn't information that's helpful, you can flag as other "needs moderator attention" and ask for a comment cleanup. This is really only useful for long comment threads. If there are just a few, you can flag them individually.

For more information, please see the [Comment Everywhere] privilege in the help center.

Answer (score 3):

If there are too many comments than are necessary, that isn't a horrible thing. It's probably good to just leave it, if they stick to the topic, they can be useful to someone.