# Flag on answer with multiple issues (mainly long comment thread) declined

Tags: support, declined-flags

I flagged an answer to [Accessing javascript variables across html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314611/accessing-javascript-variables-across-html-files/25315008#25315008) as "needs moderator attention" because it had a long comment thread, it doesn't actually solve the problem, and the correct answer was in the comment thread.

The flag was declined with the message "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

I realize that 'not an answer' flags should be used only if the answer doesn't attempt to answer the question ([Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined)). But [Flagging Help: Is it neccesary to flag comments that are 'chatty' but stick to the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253205/flagging-help-is-it-neccesary-to-flag-comments-that-are-chatty-but-stick-to-t/) says I should flag the question for cleanup due to the comments.

What should I have done in this circumstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the answer for a post is in the comments of that post rather than the post itself then you should edit the question to incorporate the information from the comments into the answer, or if you feel that you can't adequately do so while maintaining the author's voice, ask them to do so.

Only *after* the comments have been incorporated into the answer itself does it become appropriate to delete the comment thread.  And when that does happen you should use a custom moderator flag to indicate that the information in comments has since been edited into the post, and that the comments are now obsolete, you shouldn't flag the answer as not an answer.

Alternatively, you could consider posting your own answer based in part on the information in the comment thread, citing as appropriate.  This would be something to do if you felt you couldn't edit the existing answer without adding in your own additional context or if you didn't feel comfortable strictly maintaining the original author's voice and content.  If you go down this route then you wouldn't flag the comments for deletion at all.

Answer (score 3):

The title of your meta post is a bit inaccurate.

Here's the text of your flag:

> The answer doesn't actually answer the question. Instead, the actual answer is somewhere in the comments. Also, comments should be cleaned up.

Here's the title of your meta post:

> Flag on answer with multiple issues (mainly long comment thread) declined

Regarding the actual text of your flag, I probably would have declined it too:

You don't explain *why* the answer doesn't actually answer the question, and as it's been noted elsewhere, we can't judge the technical merit of answers.

Looking at the answer, there's no obvious sign that it doesn't *address* the question, and that's our chief criteria for something being an answer.

Secondly, "The comments should be cleaned up" isn't really helpful. Which ones? Why? What keeps them from being useful to future visitors?

Finally, the entire question is a mess, so I'm not surprised that the answers are a little messy.  I'm also not sure which action I should take in this instance and why.  For that reason, I opt to leave it be.

When flagging, the more detail you give us, the better. If you don't give us enough to go on, don't be surprised if we decline to take action.

Your more recent flag is an example of telling us what the problem is, why it's a problem, and gives us an understanding of the action we should take:

> The information in comments has since been edited into the post, and the comments are now obsolete.

Comment: But *even then* a moderator flag shouldn't have been used; it should've been an `obsolete` flag instead.